# Unresolved Externals when using source code from another folder

Tags: c++

I'll explain my problem as best as possible.

Basically i have two projects in one visual studio 2010 solution. One project is the source code for a game engine that i'm making, and it compiles into a .dll. The second project just contains the main.cpp file which includes files from the Engine project. I've setup the test project to include the Engine project's source directiry (headers and cpp) but i am getting unresolved externals. All my engine classes are inside a namespace.

```
main.cpp

#include <Engine/input.h>
#include <Engine/graphics.h>
#include <Engine/sound.h> 

using namespace Engine; 

int main()
{
    Renderer* renderer = new Renderer();
    etc.
}
```

Then in my code it would look like

```
Graphics.h

namespace Engine
{
    class Renderer 
    {
         void draw();
    }
}

Graphics.cpp

namespace Engine
{
    void Renderer::draw()
    {
    }
}
```

The source for the engine as mentioned above is in a separate folder to main.cpp. I've tried putting all the code into main.cpp's folder and i can compile with no problems. Having it in another folder causes the unresolved externals for the functions i use in main.cpp.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to export the symbols via `_declspec(dllexport)`.

```
namespace Engine
{
    _declspec(dllexport) class Renderer 
    {
         void draw();
    }
}
```

When you import the header, you tell it to import the symbols with `_declspec(dllimport)`. This dual functionality can be achieved with macros.

Second, you need to include the generated `.lib` file in the project settings of the project that contains `main.cpp`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer. I was going to have to do that soon anyway. But what i wanted to do is just have the test project use the source (not compiled into a dll) of the engine project folder.

Comment: Might I add that the problem is not resolved still, i wasn't actually wanting to use any dll's. Just to use source from another folder.

Comment: @rocklobster Is the source compiled?

Comment: The project compiles the source when i'm building it, it gets to the end and i get hit with a bunch of unresolved externals.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you didn't  include Graphics.h in Graphics.cpp

Comment: Sorry, i have included it, but i failed to type it in my question (the actual source file is too big and i didnt want to flood the page).

Comment: This was obviously not the problem here. It's a linker error, not a compiler one.

Comment: Correct, i'm just trying to include the source from another folder into my current test project and i'm getting these unresolved externals. I suspect it has something to do with namespaces (i never bothered to use them before this).